# sql, keep only max value and delete others

Tags: mysql, sql, max, delete-row

I have this sort of table :

---

**-id | name | memo**

-1   |  Gotham |  s1ep1

-2   |  Gotham |  s1ep3

-3   |  Gotham |  s1ep5

---

I would like to keep the entry with the max(memo) and delete others, so just keep the third one (ep5).

I can retrieve the result of all max(memo) group by name like this :

```
    SELECT id,max(memo) FROM `reminder` group by name
```

But I don't find the proper way to delete others, even looking at similar topics.

I expected something like "*delete every entries that are not in my selection*".

```
    delete from reminder where not exists (SELECT id,max(memo) FROM `reminder` group by name)
```

But it doesn't work, "*You can't specify target table 'reminder' for update in FROM clause*". I must do it badly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`:

```
delete r
    from reminder r left join
         (select name, max(memo) as maxmemo
          from reminder
          group by name
         ) rn
         on r.name = rn.name and r.memo = rn.maxmemo
    where rn.name is null;
```

As an aside.  More typically, one wants to keep the row with the highest `id`.  The structure is the same, just the columns are different:

```
delete r
    from reminder r left join
         (select name, max(id) as maxid
          from reminder
          group by name
         ) rn
         on r.name = rn.name and r.id = rn.maxid
    where rn.name is null;
```

Comment: Using `LEFT JOIN` and checking for null works. Alternatively, one could `JOIN ON r.name=rn.name` and modify WHERE clause to `WHERE r.memo != rn.maxmemo`. I have a hunch this might be faster?

Comment: @RobP . . . That is another viable approach.  I think the time is spent calculating the subquery and doing the join.  I'd be surprised if there were much difference in the performance.

Comment: Thank you, it works well, so you join `reminder r` table with `max result table rn` to use the fact that name will be NULL for other entries. I see. Do you have a good website to teach this sort of request?