# SQLite delete rows not having max index

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've tried already the search function and the most appropriate result was this, and it seems not to work for my case (?!):

[[sql, keep only max value and delete others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464495/sql-keep-only-max-value-and-delete-others][1])

I have one table like this

```
 parentassembly | "Index" | partumber 
-----------------  ------------ -------------
pA 1| _00| part1 
pa 1| _00| part2
pa 1|_ab| part1
pa 1|_ab| part3
pa 1|_af| part1
pa 1|_af| part2
pa 1|_af| part3
pa 1|_af| part4
pa 2| |part12
pa 2|| part...  
pa 2|....| .....
```

I need only the parentassembly with the highest Index and the subsequent parts.

The index can be numerical or alphanumerical or empty.

If I try the approach as shown in the link but do a count instead, I do not get a different number as all table rows

```
select count(*)
 (...or delete r....) 
from pa_save r left join
    (select parentassembly, Max("Index") as maxindex
        from pa_save
        group by parentassembly
        ) rn
        on r.ParentAssembly = rn.ParentAssembly = rn.maxindex
    where rn.ParentAssembly is null;
```

I already tried also with subqueries, also not archiving a different result...

```
delete from  pa_save 
where parentassembly not in 
    (select parentassembly from pa_save where "Index" = 
    (select MAX("Index") from pa_save as pa_save2 
          where pa_save2.parentassembly = pa_save.parentassembly));
```

Besides that it seems not to work, the subquery takes endless....

Any insight would be really appreciated.

Kind regards,

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Your first query has several syntax anomalies.  Does this do what you want?

```
select r.*
from pa_save r join
     (select parentassembly, Max("Index") as maxindex
      from pa_save
      group by parentassembly
     ) rn
     on r.ParentAssembly = rn.ParentAssembly and
        r."Index" = rn.maxindex;
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax might be not well formulated; Basically yes; the output of this query returns the one with the highest index; The Crux is at it seems, that I can't get it to run within a    `delete` command (Sqlite) ...delete all rows with a lower index   `delete from pa_save 
where parentassembly in (....)` because it deletes me than all parentassemblies returned, independent of the index.

Comment: @Tobiokanobi . . . This question is rather explicitly about `select`:  "I need only the parentassembly with the highest Index and the subsequent parts.", and this answers your question.  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.  Be explicit about what you want to do, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thx Gordon for your help it is a missunderstanding, I thought the title of the question was clear enough. (SQLite delete rows not having max index). However, I used your approach now and inserted all affected rows in new table. That is a workaround, but better than nothing.